# Sorting by Expresso Store Price within Low Search Results

Tags: expresso-store, low-search, orderby, sorting

We're using Low Search and the Low Search Store Filter to add search to our online shop. Works great but we also need to let users sort by price.

Sorting by fields which are native works fine but as 'price' is not a standard entry field passing orderby="price" has no effect.

So, is there some way to sort by price when using Low Search to display Store results?

Answer (score 2):

I see this is missing in the [Low Search Store](https://github.com/low/low_search_store) docs, but try this: `orderby="store:price"`.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work for me. I've added that paramete to low_search:results but it's not playing...

Comment: Hmm, my tests show it works. Open a GetSat thread or email me for more support?

Comment: ok, will pop you an email. Can't bear the thought of a visit to Get Satisfaction. ;)